# How to set query parameters in URL in Django

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework

I have for the moment a GET request where I have to send a body as a parameter but as in front it is not possible to make a GET request with a body I would like to pass my parameters as query parameters in the URL . How can I do this with the code I currently have?

My serializer class:

```js
@dataclass
class PlantLinkParams:
    plant_id: int
    link: str

class LnkPlantPlantByLinkSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    plant_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    link = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return PlantLinkParams(**validated_data)
```

My view class :

```js
class PlantLinkAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAnonymous,)
    queryset = LnkPlantPlant.objects.prefetch_related("plant", "plant_associated")

    def get(self, request):
        params_serializer = LnkPlantPlantByLinkSerializer(data=request.data)
        params_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        params = params_serializer.save()
        data = self.getAllPlantAssociatedByLink(params)
        serializer = ReadLnkPlantPlantSerializer(instance=data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def getAllPlantAssociatedByLink(self, params: PlantLinkParams):
        data = []
        queryset = (
            LnkPlantPlant.objects.filter(
                plant=params.plant_id,
                link=params.link,
            )
        )
        for entry in queryset:
            data.append(entry)
        return data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something simpler using a [ListAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview):

```py
class PlantLinkAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAnonymous,)
    serializer_class = ReadLnkPlantPlantSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Retrieve the query parameters (?plant_id=xxx&link=yyy)
        try:
            plant_id = int(self.request.GET.get('plant_id'))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            # Prevents plant_id to be set if not a valid integer
            plant_id = None
        link = self.request.GET.get('link')

        params = {}
        if plant_id:
            params['plant__id'] = plant_id
        if link:
            params['link'] = link

        # Only filtering the queryset if one of the params is set
        if params:
            return LnkPlantPlant.objects.filter(**params)
        return LnkPlantPlant.objects.all()
```

You don't need more than that to get your view working.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm new to Django, I'm taking over someone's project so I was wondering if your code with the params above makes it possible to have query parameters in url 
For example, I would like to have something like this: 
/api/lnk/plant/plants?plant_id=3&link=good

Comment: @PierroTH It does, the query parameters are retrieved with `self.request.GET.get(param_name)`. I'm also making sure that plant_id is an integer and only filter the queryset with the params that have been set correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help really! When I test on postman, it puts me "GET method not allowed"

Comment: @PierroTH Your view probably still inherits from APIView. GET is handled by the ListAPIView.

Comment: That was good, thank you! But I have another error in query response now: "Cannot resolve keyword &#x27;plant_id&#x27; into field. Choices are: description, id, link, plant, plant_associated" with the request url: "http ://localhost:8000/api/lnk/plant/plants?plant_id=3&amp;link=good"

Comment: @PierroTH Ah mb, I thought plant_id was a field, you should filter against plant__id (note the double underscore instead of one). I updated my answer, it should be good now.

Comment: Ohh yes it's good thank you very much for your help it's very kind! I still have a lot to learn in Django and Dajngo Rest Framework